# gojs drag/multiple selection with shift key pressed

Tags: javascript, gojs

In my gojs diagram I am using dragSelectingTool/RealtimeDragSelectingTool:

```
this.diagram = $(go.Diagram, {
    ...
    dragSelectingTool: $(
      RealtimeDragSelectingTool,
      { isPartialInclusion: true, delay: 50 },
    ...
```

Currently it works like that: when user hold mouse button less than 0.5 second it moving/shifting/panning the diagram. When user holds mouse button more than 0.5 second - the multiple selection starting (drawing rectangle to select nodes/links).

BUT I want it to work in that way: Multiple selection should only start when the shift key is pressed, else (if shith key is not pressed) it should move/shift/pann the diagram. So in case when user holds mouse button more than 0.5 second and shift key is not pressed - the diagram should be moved/shifted/panned.

It try to do it like this, but it won't works:

```
const dragSelectingTool = this.diagram.toolManager.dragSelectingTool;
dragSelectingTool.doActivate = () => {
 if(!this.diagram.lastInput.shift) return
 go.DragSelectingTool.prototype.doActivate.call(dragSelectingTool);
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Override **DragSelectingTool.canStart**:

```
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
    {
      "dragSelectingTool.canStart": function() {
        if (!this.isEnabled) return false;
        const diagram = this.diagram;
        if (!diagram.allowSelect) return false;
        const e = diagram.lastInput;
        if (!e.left) return false; // require left button
        // don't include the following checks when this tool is running modally
        if (diagram.currentTool !== this) {
          if (!this.isBeyondDragSize()) return false; // must not be a click
          // don't start if we're over a selectable part
          if (diagram.findPartAt(e.documentPoint, true) !== null) return false;
        }
        return e.shift;  // only when the Shift key is also held down
      },
```